# Merge 2 Json Results and Count Specific Values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a number of JSON such as:

**ITEM 1:**

```
{
    "countries_views": [
        {
            "thecount": "563",
            "country": "Greece"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "48",
            "country": "United States"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "11",
            "country": "Luxembourg"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "7",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "6",
            "country": "Cyprus"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "2",
            "country": "India"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "2",
            "country": "France"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "2",
            "country": "United Kingdom"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "1",
            "country": "Nigeria"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "1",
            "country": "Russia"
        }
    ]
}
```

**ITEM 2:**

```
{
    "countries_views": [
        {
            "thecount": "1037",
            "country": "Greece"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "17",
            "country": "United States"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "17",
            "country": "Cyprus"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "12",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "11",
            "country": ""
        },
        {
            "thecount": "4",
            "country": "United Kingdom"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "4",
            "country": "Australia"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "2",
            "country": "Belgium"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "1",
            "country": "Russia"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "1",
            "country": "Argentina"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And so on! What i need to do is Combine/Merge this Data in 1 array with PHP**  and i need to **add the values of Duplicates**. The end result should look something like this:

```
{
    "countries_views": [
        {
            "thecount": "**1600**",
            "country": "Greece"
        },
        {
            "thecount": "**65**",
            "country": "United States"
        },
        etcetcetc
    ]
}
```

Comment: show your code :) then i can try helping you

Comment: Hello Adrian! I am not sure how to do this i tried: json_decode and json_encode for merging but did not manage to come even close to what i need to do.

Comment: first, use `json_decode($json_object, true);` to get valid php array. Then, you'll have to create a function that merges the decoded arrays the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the JSON data, and we just traverse the array to find the duplicates and add them up.

```
<?php

// emit the code of parsing json. (see function json_decode)

$arr1 = [
    (object)['thecount' => 563, 'country' => 'Greece'],
    (object)['thecount' => 12, 'country' => 'US'],
    (object)['thecount' => 15, 'country' => 'UK'],
];

$arr2 = [
    (object)['thecount' => 1563, 'country' => 'Greece'],
    (object)['thecount' => 152, 'country' => 'CN'],
];

foreach ($arr1 as $each) {
    $exists = false;
    foreach ($arr2 as &$e) {
        if ($e->country == $each->country) {
            $e->thecount += $each->thecount;
            $exists = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$exists) {
        array_push($arr2, $each);
    }
}

$res = $arr2;

var_dump($res);
```

Here is how to get $arr1, $arr2, in your example.

```
<?php
$arr1_obj = json_decode($item1);
$arr2_obj = json_decode($item2);
$arr1 = $arr1_obj->countries_views;
$arr2 = $arr2_obj->countries_views;
```